# get_price_html changed after woocommerce Update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've updated woocommerce to the latest version and now instead of variable prices displaying as `From: £2.90` instead it displays as `£0.90 - £2.90`.  I'd like to revert back to old display.

I'm attempting a filter using but how do i put `From:` in front of the price like the older woocommerce versions?   The below code get's the minimum price but `From:` isn't displayed.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpa83367_price_html', 100, 2 );
function wpa83367_price_html( $price, $product ){

    $price = "From: "; 

    $price.= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: which command do you upgrade from, and to ?

Comment: i upgraded from woocommerce 2.0 to 2.37

Comment: I tried that code and it's working.. http://reigelgallarde.me/product/woocommerce-woorei-shop-manager/

Comment: Does it work on the category page?

Comment: yes it does work on category http://reigelgallarde.me/product-category/plugins/